# How do I make an upper-diagonal matrix from a matrix A in ARM?

Tags: matrix, arm, raspberry-pi

I have an assignment to write some code in ARM on a Raspberry Pi Model B.

The first part of the assignment is to take a given square matrix A, and turn it into an upper-diagonal matrix.

I have this algorithm:

Ax=b

Data: A pointer to a Square Matrix `A`; a column vector `b` and the size `N` in File `matrix.s`

Result: The upper triangular matrix written nicely on the terminal. I arrange the matrix and the vector so that it is in this form in memory: `M=[a11 a12 b1; a21 a22 b2]`

```
for i=1...N+1 do
    for j=i+1...N do
        for k=1...N+1 do
            Pk= -(Mik/Mii)*Mji
        end
        for k=1...N+1 do
            Mjk=Pk+Mjk
        end
    end
end
```

I managed to make a decent divider function, but I can't figure out how to make the matrix `A` into an upper-diagonal matrix.